# Progress bar line disappears inside another element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, progress-bar

This is the CSS I am using.

```
.qualitybar {   
    overflow: hidden;
    color: lightgrey
}

.qualitybar .status_verified {
    color: #5cb85c;
}

.qualitybar .status_needs_verification {
    color: #f0ad4e;
}

.qualitybar .status_needs_id {
    color: #d9534f;
}

.qualitybar .status_needs_tags {
    color: darkslategray;
}

.qualitybar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400
}

.qualitybar .needs_tags:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c"
}

.qualitybar .needs_id:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c"
}

.qualitybar .needs_verification:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c"
}

.qualitybar .verified_id:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c"
}

.qualitybar li:before {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 45px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: lightgray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    padding: 2px
}

.qualitybar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: -1
}

.qualitybar li.status_verified:before,
.qualitybar li.status_verified:after {
    background: #5cb85c;
}

.qualitybar li.status_needs_verification:before,
.qualitybar li.status_needs_verification:after {
    background: #f0ad4e;
}


.qualitybar li.status_needs_id:before,
.qualitybar li.status_needs_id:after {
    background: #d9534f;
}


.qualitybar li.status_needs_tags:before,
.qualitybar li.status_needs_tags:after {
    background: darkslategray;
}


.qualitybar li:last-child:after {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%
}


.qualitybar li:first-child:after {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%
}

.qualitybar li:last-child:after {
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px
}

.qualitybar li:first-child:after {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            
                            <ul class="qualitybar">
                                <li class="status_verified needs_tags"><strong>Step 1</strong></li>
                                <li class="status_verified needs_id"><strong>Step 2</strong></li>
                                <li class="status_verified needs_verification"><strong>Step 3</strong></li>
                                <li class="status_verified verified_id"><strong>Step 4</strong></li>
                            </ul>
                            
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    
                    <ul class="qualitybar">
                        <li class="status_verified needs_tags"><strong>Step 1</strong></li>
                        <li class="status_verified needs_id"><strong>Step 2</strong></li>
                        <li class="status_verified needs_verification"><strong>Step 3</strong></li>
                        <li class="status_verified verified_id"><strong>Step 4</strong></li>
                    </ul>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am using bootstrap. This is the problem I am experiencing

[image: 2 Progress Bars]

As shown in the screenshot, the top progress bar is not showing the lines, even though it's the same code as the bottom progress bar.

Based on other similar solutions posted, I tried changing the `z-index` to be 1. But this is happening --

[image: Progress Bar with a strike]

How do I get the progress bar working within a card-header without any strikes?

Comment: It is nowhere near the same: true, both `qualitybar` are equal in the `<body>`, but they have different parents. Please show the parent CSS as they probably mess up the `z-index`

Comment: Without using anything bootstrap they look the same. Did you test it like that? [image](https://i.postimg.cc/Pxtm1Z61/SO62272704.jpg)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. But I haven't checked it without bootstrap. This is going into a website with bootstrap all over. So it is important that this works within bootstrap.

Comment: (Fiddle) In the topbar `<li class="status_verified needs_tags">` (other 3 too) have property `overflow-wrap: break-word` set. The bottom bar version doesn't have that. Checked with Developer Tools. The specific CSS doing it is not available in the code you posted nor in the Fiddle. `overflow-wrap` is not a standard CSS property, probably my (recent) W10 Firefox DE, but it is translated into `word-wrap: break-word`, inherited from `.card`. Bottombar doesn't have parent `.card`, so not the same as you claimed. Also, if it runs in plain HTML it should run fine in bootstrap. Something's off.

Comment: **cont'd** apparently, `.card` child elements inherit the `word-wrap` property. Not sure if that causes the problem, for now I am only checking for differences. Maybe setting the topbar `<li>`s to default `word-wrap: normal` will work. (just checked: `.status_verified: normal` does not).

Comment: `.card` comes from bootstrap. So I am assuming the `word-wrap` property (and other associated CSS) comes from that. I think David's solution below comes close, but it's still missing something.

Comment: You and me both, still, the code you posted does not show the problem (plain HTML, that is). So it has to be some bootstrap setting.

Comment: One step further: the classnames in your CSS differ from the ones you use in HTML. You should see 4 colors, but only see one, namely 'green'. CSS: `status_needs_id` in HTML: `needs_id` (the other steps too!!). You will need to correct that first....

Comment: The four colors part is unrelated. https://imgur.com/a/u7otZDw This is the complete screenshot. I had 3 other progress bars as well.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was because of -1 index on `.qualitybar li:after`. To better understand why the lines are not showing on the top but on the bottom, we need to look at:

1. In what order are elements stacked, [if `z-index` is not specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)
2. How is `z-index` going to influence the stacking order, inside so-called "[the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)"

In summary：

- `z-index` is a non-inherited property. Hence when you don't specify it on an element, its initial value will be used, which is `auto`
- When `z-index` is not specified, elements are stacked by default in the following order (from farthest to closest to the observer)

  1. The background and borders of the root element (`<html>`)
  2. Descendant non-positioned blocks (`position: static;`)
  3. Descendant positioned blocks
- To change the default stacking order, you can use `z-index` on a positioned element
- A stacking context is formed by positioned elements with `z-index` value other than `auto` (there are other scenarios where a stacking context is formed as well)
- Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking order of the parent stacking context

Enough said. Going back to your problem...

On the top progress bar, there is no positioned element with a `z-index` value other than `auto`, except `.qualitybar li:after`, which has -1 `z-index` value. So the only stacking context is the root context:

- root stacking context `<html />`

  - div class="card"
  - div class="card-header"
  - div class="row"
  - div class="col-md-12"
  - ul class="qualitybar"
  - li class="status_verified"
  - li::before
  - strong
  - li::after  <-- z-index: -1;

So `.qualitybar li:after` sits behind all other elements within the root context. And since `.card` has white background, the lines are covered by the white background and hence not showing.

On the bottom progress bar, same thing happened. There is only one root stacking context, but since there is no `.card` and all other elements have transparent backgrounds, the lines are showing.

#### Quick Fix

You definitely still need `z-index:-1;` on the lines, which is styled by `.qualitybar li:after`, because you don't want the lines to show up on top of the step dots. But you don't want the lines to be hidden so far behind other elements. The quick fix is to create a stacking context on the `.qualitybar li` itself.

Remember, to create a stacking context, you only need to add `z-index` value other than `auto` on a positioned element. `.qualitybar li` is already styled with relative position. So you just need to add a `z-index` value that is greater than -1.

```css
.qualitybar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 400;

    z-index: 0;
}
```

And since the stacking context is self-contained. The lines will be hidden among elements within the `.qualitybar li` stacking context. But the `.qualitybar li` elements have the same `z-index:auto;` among other elements under the root stacking context.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/tnuckrfd/13/

#### Fix for the strikes

The reason why you see strikes into the step dots is because of the following:

```css
.qualitybar li:last-child:after {
    ...
    left: -50%;
}
```

You have the bar start from a negative left 50% hence it strikes out the icon.

My fixes are the following:

```css
.qualitybar {
    ...
    padding-left: 0;   /* Remove the left padding, or use `list-unstyled` */
}

...

.qualitybar li:first-child:after {
    left: calc(50% + 50px/2);  /* Start from 50% + half of your icon's width */
}

.qualitybar li:first-child:after,
.qualitybar li:last-child:after {
    width: calc(50% - 50px/2);  /* Instead of 100% width, you only want this wide */
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/tnuckrfd/65/

Comment: I think this is working partially. As you can see in the demo, there is a strike in the third bubble (Step 3). Does something else need to be changed?

Comment: I guess the solution would be to change `left` on `.qualitybar li:last-child:after` and `.qualitybar li:first-child:after` to be `-45%` and `55%` instead of `-50%` and `50%`. I feel like that's a hacky solution. Is there a better solution?

Comment: David, I'm not a 100% sure, but `z-index` is 'stacking context' dependend, not necessarily 'element positioning' dependend, although `z-index` is most often used in conjunction with positioning. [MDN: The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) and [MDN: Using z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index). Just making sure the right info is passed on.... When you agree, please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @RenevanderLende: I think by saying "z-index only works on positioned elements", I only meant it applies to positioned elements. If you add z-index on a non-positioned element, such as `position: static;`, it won't have any effect. But you're right on the stacking context. If you add z-index on a positioned element, it will create a stacking context. I will edit my answer and try my best to make everything a little bit clearer. Thanks!